# Include systemd-journal-upload in Google Container-Optimized OS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, systemd, google-container-os, systemd-journal-remote

Unfortunately Google's Container-Optimized OS image doesn't come with [systemd-journal-upload](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/systemd-journal-upload.8.html), although it should be generally available after systemd [version 216](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS#L3869). *(The current stable image ships with version 232.)*

It's possible to [build your own image](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/building-from-open-source), but I can't figure out how to include systemd-journal-upload.

Is it just a [--enable-remote](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/journal-remote/meson.build#L41) flag in file [overlay-lakitu/sys-apps/systemd/systemd-232.ebuild](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/overlays/board-overlays/+/master/overlay-lakitu/sys-apps/systemd/systemd-232.ebuild) maybe?

Comment: Have you tried with the "--enable-remote" flag? If yes, please open customer issue along with the error generated, through this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Comment: I tried with --enable-remote but that didn't do it for me. Meaning, systemd-journal-upload was not compiled.

Comment: Please open up a 'customer issue' in the [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#search_and_create_feature_requests_by_product) specified above (Go to Compute > Create new Container Registry issue )

Comment: I created the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71815341

Comment: Please follow that [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/71815341) as any future updates will be posted there.